# Clojure Enlive: A selector that uses regex

Tags: regex, clojure, enlive

I'm trying to select the :li node that has, in is content, the word "(SCIAN":

```
<li>...</li>
<li class="">
                Conception de systèmes informatiques et services connexes (SCIAN 541510)
            </li>

<li>...</li>
```

I've fail trying this:

```
(html/select
    fetched
    [[:li (html/has [(html/re-pred #"\w*SCIAN\b")])]])))
```

Thank you for your help!

Notice: I've tried use these patterns without success so I might do something wrong:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/enlive-clj/thlhc5zBRUw

Answer (score 1):

I think the regex in combination with french accents causes the problem:

```
    (def s "è")
    (def r #"\w") 
    (re-matches r s)
    ;;; => nil
    (def s "e")
    (re-matches r s)
    ;;; => "e"
```

Comment: You are right! I found a solution, we can do: `(re-matches #"\p{L}+" "è")`

Comment: ... though I am not yet good at regex and can't get a working solution. What would be the proper regex selector to use?

Answer (score 1):

To make that work, we actually don't need to use regex:

```
(html/select
    fetched
    [[:li (html/pred #(.contains (html/text %) "SCIAN"))]])
```